# Problema con el alto de un div

Tags: css, bootstrap

Tengo una estructura con dos columnas, en la primera hay una imagen de fondo y en la segunda un pequeño formulario.
El problema esta situado en la primera columna, ahí tengo un carousel con dos imagenes que ocupan todo el alto. Sin embargo cuando hago scroll me doy cuenta de que el carousel no ocupa todo el alto quedando un "trozo de fondo sin imagen".
Mi duda es como hacer que la imagen ocupe toda la columna, que al hacer scroll hasta abaja se vea que la imagen ocupe todo.
Para explicarme mejor dejo una captura de pantalla en la cual hice scroll hasta llegar al final de la web y se ve como hay una ultima zona sin la imagen con el color de fondo.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Código html:

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-7 d-none d-lg-block p-0">
            <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-bs- 
            ride="carousel">
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <div class="carousel-item active img-first min-vh-100"></div>
                    <div class="carousel-item img-second min-vh-100"></div>
                </div>
            <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs- 
            target="#carouselExampleControls" data-bs-slide="prev">
                <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
            </button>
            <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs- 
            target="#carouselExampleControls" data-bs-slide="next">
                <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
            </button>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-5>
            <!-->Contenido<-->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Código css de imagenes

```css
.img-first {
    background-image: url('./../img/img_01.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}

.img-second {
    background-image: url('./../img/img_02.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

La versión de bootstrap que estoy usando es la v5.0

Comment: Con el inspector de elementos, prueba de ver si es un slide u otro el que ponga ese trozo de sobra, puede que alguno de esos slides sea más grande de lo debido y sea ese el motivo por el cual ves el trozo que sobra.

Comment: @Zander es por culpa de del alto del carousel que no ocupa todo el alto del ```<div class="col-7 d-none d-lg-block p-0">```. Cuando compruebo si se adapta bien a diferentes tamaños de pantalla y reduzco el alto tengo que hacer scroll para poder ver todo el formulario y al hacerlo pasa lo de la imagen